# Abstracting format specifiers in C stdlib functions (e.g. printf, scanf)

Tags: c, string-formatting, c-preprocessor

It may be the case that we start with an initial type that is heavily used in I/O calls and wish to change the type later. For instance, say we have:

```
typedef unsigned short int board_idx;
//...
board_idx k_in;
scanf("%10hu", &k_in);
```

If we later change the type of `board_idx`, it would be arduous to go back and change all such format specifiers to match this later.

I first guessed a good approach would be to define an associated string literal for the format specifier (preferably right next to the type definition of `board_idx`), and then insert this in to all relevant places in format specifiers. However, this also seems somewhat arduous (using e.g. `strcat`), so I wonder what others would do in this situation?

Building on the approach at [How to replace a piece of const char* with another string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616105/how-to-replace-a-piece-of-const-char-with-another-string-in-c) suggests that we might be able to do that if we encapsulate the string replacing code in a function that can be applied to format specifiers with unique identifiers that correspond to the respective type. In the above `scanf` example, this could be:

```
"%10hu" // should be initially "%board_idx", which can then be replaced
```

A disadvantage of this method is runtime cost, so I now think a preprocessor solution may be best as long as all the strings the format specifiers are embedded in are known at compile time, e.g:

```
// Untested and probably won't work ... I'll call it pseudocode:
#define STR(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STR(x) 
//
#define BOARD_IDX_FMT = %10hu
// "my input is %10hu" becomes:
#define FMTSPEC STRINGIFY(my input is ) #BOARD_IDX_FMT 
printf(FMTSPEC);
```

But this too would be very complex for strings with many format specifiers.

Comment: Just put quotes in your macro and avoid all that garble.. `#define BOARD_IDX_FMT "%10hu"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, this also seems somewhat arduous (using e.g. strcat)

In C, adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated at compile time

```
"asd" "qwe"  --> "asdqwe"
```

so something along these lines should work

```
#define FMT "%d"
printf("Hello " FMT "!\n", 17);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can simply cast the value instead of touching format and use:

```
printf("Hello %d \n", (int)k_in);
```

to print and

```
int n;
scanf("%10u", &n);
k_in = (board_idx) n;
```

to read your `k_in`.